# How to access map values in golang

Tags: arrays, string, go, struct

When I perform a `POST` request it sends the `raw-data` like below.

```
products%5B%22producs-1%22%5D%5B%22pink%22%5D%3D1%26products%5B%22products-2%22%5D%5B%22black%22%5D%3D2%26products%5B%22products-3%22%5D%5B%22green%22%5D%3D2%27
```

When I do URL ParseQuery it shows output like this:

```golang
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(body))
    params, _ := url.ParseQuery(string(body))
    fmt.Println(params)
```

```
map[products["products-1"]["black"]:[2] products["products-2"]["green"]:[2] products["products-3"]["pink"]:[1]]
```

I want to access **products-1**, **black**, **2**(other fields also), how can I do this?

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/16

Answer (score 1):

That is a rather strange format and looks like it is expecting a PHP script. Or some other scripting language.

The ParseQuery function has made a map but the key is a string that looks like "products["products-2"]["green"]"

I assume it would be better to have a "products" map that contains an "attributes" map or something like that. I'm not sure how to get there without a lot of effort

Answer (score 1):

try loop by keys to get what are the keys:

```
  for k, v := range params { 
    fmt.Printf("key[%s] value[%s]\n", k, v)
  }
```